# Audio recording script quality bad using Gsreamer

Tags: python, audio, gstreamer

Thanks to this amazing community i finished my project about capturing audio from an audio input and saving it to a faile using gstreamer

Now i would like to refine the quality of the capture, since my script saves the audio as mono with 80kbps on 44100 hz. I would like to make it atleast stereo on 128 kbps

here is the code. P.S. feel free to use it anywhere you wish!

```
import gi
import datetime, time
import sys
import signal  
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, Gtk
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

autoaudiosrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosrc", "autoaudiosrc")
audioconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("audioconvert", "audioconvert")
audioresample= Gst.ElementFactory.make("audioresample","audioresample")
vorbisenc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("vorbisenc", "vorbisenc")
oggmux = Gst.ElementFactory.make("oggmux", "oggmux")
filesink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesink", "filesink")
url = datetime.datetime.now()
audioresample.quality=10
filesink.set_property("location",url)
pipeline.add( autoaudiosrc)
pipeline.add( audioconvert)
pipeline.add( vorbisenc)
pipeline.add( oggmux)
pipeline.add( filesink)
pipeline.add( audioresample)

autoaudiosrc.link( audioconvert)
audioconvert.link( audioresample)
audioresample.link( vorbisenc)
vorbisenc.link( oggmux)
oggmux.link( filesink)

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Please tell us, what have you tried, and why didn't it work/what errors were you getting?

Comment: As you can see in the code i tried audioresample with the best quality to no avail. The audioconvert line should convert it in stereo sound, but that is not working either...
right now im trying to set the   “noise-shaping”   feature on and will report back

Answer (score 0):

```
import gi
import datetime, time
import sys
import signal  
signal.alarm(15)
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, Gtk
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

autoaudiosrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosrc", "autoaudiosrc")
audioconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("audioconvert", "audioconv")
audioresample= Gst.ElementFactory.make("audioresample","audioresample")
vorbisenc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("vorbisenc", "vorbisenc")
oggmux = Gst.ElementFactory.make("oggmux", "oggmux")
filesink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesink", "filesink")
url = datetime.datetime.now()

audioresample.set_property("quality", 10) 
vorbisenc.set_property("quality", 1)

filesink.set_property("location",url)
pipeline.add( autoaudiosrc)
pipeline.add( audioconvert)
pipeline.add( vorbisenc)
pipeline.add( oggmux)
pipeline.add( filesink)
pipeline.add( audioresample)

autoaudiosrc.link( audioconvert)
audioconvert.link( audioresample)
audioresample.link(vorbisenc)
vorbisenc.link( oggmux)
oggmux.link( filesink)

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

Gtk.main()
```

There,it's smooth and ok now, i like it ( i probably don't have to have audioconvert, but it smooths the quality a tad bit, was trying a lot of other things but this is the best quality i can get)